# rails newest record with grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need the "nps" field value from the latest Feedback record for each account based on the created_at date which is a datetime field. I have worked on this, but it's pulling back the first record for each account. Am I going obviously wrong somewhere?

```
nps_total = 0
nps_records = Feedback.select([:nps, 'MAX(created_at)']).group(:account_id).each do |record| 
  nps_total += record.nps
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I understood, you have 2 models : Account and Feedback and `Account has_many :feedbacks`. Now, your Feedback model has a "nps" value.

If I'm right, you just have to do something like

```
nps_total = 0
Account.all.each do |account|
 nps_total += account.feebacks.order("created_at").last.nps
end
```

Comment: This would *almost* work, except I don't think the association maintains order by `create_at`. However, with an appropriate `scope` added to `Feedback`, this could work.

Comment: Seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870531/find-the-newest-record-in-rails-3), I think you're right, I'm gonna update my answer :)