# Find a newly created record in a controller test using RSpec 3 and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, actioncontroller, rspec3

I'm doing a controller spec in Rails 4, and I'm wanting to test the attributes of a record created by a controller action. How do I find the newly created record?

For example, what could I do instead of

```
it 'Marks a new user as pending' do
  post :create, params
  # I don't want to use the following line
  user = User.last
  expect(user).to be_pending
end
```

The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) only briefly talks about controller tests, where it mentions testing that `Article.count` changes by 1, but not how to get a new ActiveRecord model.

The question [Find the newest record in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870531/find-the-newest-record-in-rails-3) is about Rails 3.

I'm reluctant to use `User.last`, because the default sorting may be by something other than creation date.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to compare `records` or `objects` in controller tests. In a controller `create` test, you should test the correct redirection and the changing of the record.

You can easily `compare` your objects in a model test, because you can easily track your record.

Still, you can access the created record from a test if your `action` has a `variable` that holds the `record` like

In controller

```
 def create 
   @user = #assign user
 end
```

In Test

```
assigns(:user).name.should eq "Name" # If it has a name attribute
assigns(:user).pending.should be_true # I don't know how you implemented pending
```

You can take a look at [this article](http://codecrate.com/2014/11/rspec-controllers-best-practices.html)

Comment: I mean it for something like you can assign a `record` to a `variable`, then can operate with that `variable` eg. `let(:user) { Fabricate.build :user }`  now `user` will be available in your example and you can operate `user` eg. `expect(user.disabled?).to be_true`

Comment: I've tried fixing the grammar of your answer. Did I inadvertently change any of the meaning? Also, with "and test the changing of the record", do you mean testing whether an individual record is changed, or testing whether the number of records has changed?

Comment: thanks, sorry for  my bad English, I have edit the line, I thinks I will be more understandable now :)

Answer (score 2):

If a controller has an instance variable named `@user`, then we can access it in RSpec by `assigns(:user)`.

Comment: I'm a little concerned that that would breaking encapsulation.