# Rspec testing attributes after creating record in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Background: I've got an `after_action` callback in my controller, which takes the string `address`, processes it and stores `longitude` and `latitude` in corresponding fields. I want to test this.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682671/how-to-complete-the-rspec-put-controller-test-from-scaffold), as well as [this article](https://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html) only consider update methods, but at least, they are quite clear, because I've already got an object to work with.

So my question is - how to find this newly created record? [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731143/find-a-newly-created-record-in-a-controller-test-using-rspec-3-and-rails-4) led me to this code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::Settings::GeneralSettingsController, type: :controller do

  context "POST methods" do
    describe "#edit and #create" do
      it "encodes and stores lang/lot correctly" do
          post :create, general_setting: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:general_setting)
          expect(assigns(:general_setting).long).to eq(37.568021)
          # expect(general_setting.long).to eq(37.568021)
          # expect(general_setting.lat).to eq(55.805553)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But using the code in the answer, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:general_setting).long).to eq(37.568021)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `long' for nil:NilClass
```

Update #1:
This is my new controller spec code:

```
RSpec.describe Admin::Settings::GeneralSettingsController, type: :controller do

  context 'POST methods' do
    before(:each) do
      allow(subject).to receive(:set_long_lat)
    end

    describe 'post create' do
      before(:each) do
        post :create, params: { general_setting: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:general_setting) }
      end

      it "saves the record with valid attributes" do
        expect{subject}.to change{GeneralSetting.count}.by(1)
      end

      it 'calls :set_long_lat' do
        expect(subject).to have_received(:set_long_lat)
      end
    end
  end

  describe '#set_long_lat' do
    # spec for method
  end
end
```

Update #2:

Here is my controller code:

```
class Admin::Settings::GeneralSettingsController < AdminController
  include CrudConcern

  before_action :find_general_setting, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update, :set_long_lat]
  after_action :set_long_lat

  def index
    @general_settings = GeneralSetting.all
  end

  def new
    @general_setting = GeneralSetting.new
    # Билдим для того, что бы было видно сразу одно поле и пользователь не должен
    # кликать на "добавить телефон"
    @general_setting.phones.build
    @general_setting.opening_hours.build
  end

  def edit
    # Тоже самое, что и с нью - если телефонов нет вообще, то показываем одно пустое поле
    if @general_setting.phones.blank?
      @general_setting.phones.build
    end

    if @general_setting.opening_hours.blank?
      @general_setting.opening_hours.build
    end
  end

  def create
    @general_setting = GeneralSetting.new(general_setting_params)
    create_helper(@general_setting, "edit_admin_settings_general_setting_path")
  end

  def destroy
    destroy_helper(@general_setting, "admin_settings_general_settings_path")
  end

  def update
    # debug
    # @general_setting.update(language: create_hash(params[:general_setting][:language]))
    @general_setting.language = create_hash(params[:general_setting][:language])
    update_helper(@general_setting, "edit_admin_settings_general_setting_path", general_setting_params)
  end


  private

  def set_long_lat
    geocoder = Geocoder.new
    data = geocoder.encode!(@general_setting.address)
    @general_setting.update!(long: data[0], lat: data[1])
  end

  def find_general_setting
    @general_setting = GeneralSetting.find(params[:id])
  end

  def general_setting_params
    params.require(:general_setting).permit(GeneralSetting.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(
      phones_attributes: [:id, :value, :_destroy, :general_setting_id ]).push(
      opening_hours_attributes: [:id, :title, :value, :_destroy, :deneral_setting_id]) )
  end

  def create_hash(params)
    language_hash = Hash.new

    params.each do |param|
      language_hash[param.to_sym] = param.to_sym
    end
    return language_hash
  end
end
```

(If it helps - I've got a lot of similar crud-actions, that is why I've put them all in a concern controller)

```
module CrudConcern 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Language

  included do
    helper_method :create_helper, :update_helper, :destroy_helper, :get_locales
  end

  def get_locales
    @remaining_locales = Language.get_remaining_locales
  end

  def create_helper(object, path)
    if object.save!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          redirect_to send(path, object)
          flash[:primary] = "Well done!"
        }
      end
    else
      render :new
      flash[:danger] = "Something not quite right"
    end
    @remaining_locales = Language.get_remaining_locales
  end

  def update_helper(object, path, params)
    if object.update!(params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          redirect_to send(path, object)
          flash[:primary] = "Well done!"
        }
      end
    else
      render :edit
      flash[:danger] = "Something's not quite right"
    end
  end

  def destroy_helper(object, path)
    if object.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          redirect_to send(path)
          flash[:primary] = "Well done"    
        }
      end
    else
      render :index
      flash[:danger] = "Something's not quite right"
    end
  end

end
```

Update #3
It's not the ideal solution, but, somehow, controller tests just won't work. I've moved my callback into the model and updated my `general_setting_spec` test.

```
class GeneralSetting < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :set_long_lat    
  validates :url, presence: true

  private

  def set_long_lat
    geocoder = Geocoder.new
    data = geocoder.encode(self.address)
    self.update_column(:long, data[0])
    self.update_column(:lat, data[1])
  end
end
```

My tests now:

```
RSpec.describe GeneralSetting, type: :model do

  let (:regular) { FactoryGirl.build(:general_setting) } 

  describe "checking other validations" do
    it "is invalid with no url" do
      expect{
        invalid.save
      }.not_to change(GeneralSetting, :count)
    end

    it 'autofills the longitude' do
      expect{ regular.save }.to change{ regular.long }.from(nil).to(37.568021)
    end

    it 'autofills the latitude' do
      expect{ regular.save }.to change{ regular.lat }.from(nil).to(55.805078)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Current RSpec version discourages testing assings in controller. Why don't you want to use `GeneralSetting.last`?

Answer (score 0):

I would test expectation that controller calls method specified in `after_action` and make a separate test for that  method.

Something like:

```
context 'POST methods' do
  before(:each) do
    allow(subject).to receive(:method_from_callback)
  end

  describe 'post create' do
    before(:each) do
      post :create, params: { general_setting: attributes_for(:general_setting) }
    end

    it 'calls :method_from_callback' do
      expect(subject).to have_received(:method_from_callback)
    end
  end
end

describe '#method_from_callback' do
  # spec for method
end
```

Be sure to use your method name instead of `:method_from_callback` pay attention that I've used rspec 3.5 syntax (wrapped request request parameters into `params`).

Comment: Sorry for a bit of off-topic, but I can't additionally make the simple create action pass:
`describe 'post create' do
      before(:each) do
        post :create, params: { general_setting: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:general_setting) }
      end

      it "saves the record with valid attributes" do
        expect{subject}.to change{GeneralSetting.count}.by(1)
      end

      it 'calls :set_long_lat' do
        expect(subject).to have_received(:set_long_lat)
      end
    end`

It says `expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0` Could the callback be the issue?

Comment: Probably. I usually use bang versions (`create!` or `save!`) in actual controller when I think that it works, but rspec shows that it doesn't. This will at least throw exception into console.

Comment: It's a bit hard to read in a comment, I've updated my question. Besides, for the callback, I now receive this error:
`expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments`

Comment: Then maybe it is not called afterwards :) Can you also add controller code?

Comment: Besides, I'm not sure that `expect {subject}.to change{GeneralSetting.count}` will do what you expect it to do, because `before` callback will fire before `it`. I usually use other form: `let(:action) { -> { post :create, ....} }` and then `expect(action).to change(ModelName, :count)`.

Comment: Everything looks like it should work. I think there is some problem with rspec syntax. What version of rspec and rails do you use? Because for rails 4 one should not wrap request parameters into `params`. So it will be just `post :create, general_setting: attributes_for(:general_setting)`. And the rest would be the same.

Comment: I'm using:
`rspec -v
3.5.4
rails -v
Rails 5.0.2`

Comment: You also have `set_long_lat` in `before_action` in `only`. Should it be there? And I think that is is the key as it responds with http 404. Add checking happy path: `it 'responds with HTTP 200' { expect(response).to have_http_status(:success) }`

Comment: I think yes, it should be here because I call :find_general_setting for this method (need the @general_setting variable to access the address field).

However, now, I moved all the code from controller to the model (updated my question) and moved my tests from controller to the model spec. Now it works. I still receive the error, that upon saving the GeneralSetting count was not increased by 1, even if no callback are now involved. Strange...

Comment: But it uses `find` with `params[:id]` and there is no `params[:id]` in `create`. So I think you get the following sequence: `create` and then `find_general_setting`, which raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, so `set_long_lat` is never called indeed.

Comment: I've added the path check  `Add checking happy path: it 'responds with HTTP 200' { expect(response).to have_http_status(:success) }` and the output is `expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302`. My `expect(subject).to have_received` test results in: `expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments`

Comment: That should be actually redirect for `create`, yes. You can also try to use `expect(subject).to receive(:set_long_lat)` in `bafore(:each)` and remove expectation that it has received from `it`, but I think you'll get the same result. That's come kind of black magic or we both miss something obvious.